# Javascript iteration with thymeleaf, how to pass index to array in thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, iteration, thymeleaf

I'm setting 2 select in html, the second one depends of the first one, so I use a script "onchange", so when the first value of the select change, the second one change too, I don't know how to get the variable of my FOR to get the index of the thymeleaf model in my script

SCRIPT-
So my problem here it's inside the if when I tried to get the value of documentos[i].proyecto.id, but I can get documentos[0, 1 or any number].proyecto.id

```
/*<![CDATA[*/
    function load(){
        var e = document.getElementById("proyecto-id");
        var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var sub = document.getElementById("documento-id");
        var length = sub.options.length;
        for (z = 0; z < length; z++) {
          sub.options[z] = null;
        }
        for(i=0;i<[[${#lists.size(documentos)}]];i++){
            if([[${documentos[ i ].proyecto.id}]] == value){
                var opt = document.createElement('option');
                opt.value = [[${documentos[ i ].id}]]
                opt.text = [[${documentos[ i ].nombre}]];
                sub.add(opt);
            }
        }
    }
/*]]>*/
```

HTML select

```
<select id="proyecto-id" class="custom-select" th:onchange="load()">
                    <option th:each="p : ${proyectos}"
                            th:text="${p.nombre}"
                            th:value="${p.id}">
                    </option> 
</select>
<select id="documento-id" class="custom-select">
</select>
```